# Java POI - convert Workbook to File

Tags: java, excel, file, apache-poi

I need to return a Workbook but converted to Java `File` object.
For now I only know how to write the Workbook to the disk with `workbook.write(outputStream)`. However, I want to return the `File` object in order to use it directly for further processing (uploading to Amazon).

My code:

```
public File addErrorColumnToExcel(MultipartFile file, HashMap<Integer, String> errors, int newColumnIndex) throws IOException {
    Workbook workbook = null;
    Sheet sheet = null;
    Row row;
    Cell newErrorCell;
    String errorText;

    try {
      workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new BufferedInputStream(file.getInputStream()));
      sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(FIRST_SHEET_INDEX);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.error("cannot get the file: " + file.getOriginalFilename() + e);
    }

    //do some logic

    return workbook; //but I need to convert this to a java File
  }
```

Comment: Why do you want to return a `MultipartFile`? This type usually represents an uploaded file (Spring Web)... It probably would be beneficial to know what you want to do with the output later.

Comment: Greetings, I need a File actually, I modified the post. I need this File in order to upload it to amazon, i need its metadata to create this object: PutObjectRequest(String bucketName, String key, InputStream input, ObjectMetadata metadata)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a temporary file and write the data to this file before returning it. Don't forget to delete the file after processing. Here is a simplified snippet:

```java
public File getEmptyExcelFile() throws IOException {
    try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {

        workbook.createSheet("test"); // do some logic

        File outputFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".xlsx");
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
            workbook.write(fos);
        }
        return outputFile;
    }
}
```

*Note that I use try-with-resources for the `XSSFWorkbook` and `FileOutputStream`.*

---

Another idea would be to return a byte array `byte[]` instead of a `File`. This is a somewhat cleaner solution and does not write the file to the disk.

```java
public byte[] getEmptyExcelFileAsBytes() throws IOException {
    try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {

        workbook.createSheet("test"); // do some logic

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        workbook.write(baos);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used a similar idea to byte[] but instead used a InputStreamFile, I converted the workbook to InputStreamFile and then extracted some metadata from the original file (original excel wihout modifications) and with that I can upload that InputStream to S3. Thank you!